# Loop will not reach sentinel value - Java

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have a while loop in my program that won't hit the sentinel value. The program basically reads in a database which includes a string, an int, and a double and then it loops back through. My problem is that it seems to not read in the sentinel, and then an infinite loop occurs. I've tried to fix this for many hours so any assistance would be very helpful. A sample input would look like this where EndSearchKeys is equal to SECSENT.

Also assume that any method called is not the problem, because I've already deleted that and tested again.

Lexus 2005 23678.0 
Ford 2001 7595.0 
Honda 2004 15500.0 
EndSearchKeys

```
while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        if(carMake.equals(SECSENT))
        {
            break;
        }
        if(scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            carYear = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR - not an int");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            carPrice = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR - not a double");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        Car key = new Car(carMake, carYear, carPrice);
        // Stores the output of seqSearch in pos.

        // If the debug switch is on, then it prints these statements.
        if(DEBUG_SW == true)
        {   
            System.out.println("Search, make = " + key.getMake());
            System.out.println("Search, year = " + key.getYear());
            System.out.println("Search, price = " + key.getPrice());
        }   
        System.out.println("key =");
        System.out.println(key);
        pos = seqSearch(carArr, count, key);
        if(pos != -1)
        {
            System.out.println("This vehicle was found at index = " + pos);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("This vehicle was not found in the database.");
        }
        if(scan.hasNext())
        {
             carMake = scan.next();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR - not a String");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is kind of confusing.  Scanning a database should never result in an infinite loop.  Even if your sentinel value is not reached, the end of the database should be reached.  Is `SECSENT` a string?  Try printing `carMake` to console at the beginning of each loop (right before the sentinel check).  Put the sentinel value near the beginning of the database, and see what prints when you should be expecting the sentinel to print.

Comment: In general, you should have only one .hasNext() in your loop.

Comment: Tested EndSearchKeys in the middle and it did exit the loop. It seems like it never reads it when it's at the end for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You say in your response above that the problem only occurs when you make the sentinel the final value in the database.  Here is what is happening.

At the very end of your loop, you do this:

```
    if(scan.hasNext())
    {
         carMake = scan.next();
    }
```

Now, `carMake` = `your sentinel value`.

The loop goes to start again, and performs this test:

```
while(scan.hasNext())
```

But scan does **not** have next.  You "consumed" next above (at the end of the previous loop iteration).  Right now, "next" is "null."  So the loop is not entered, and your test at the beginning of the loop (below) is never reached.

```
    if(carMake.equals(SECSENT))
    {
        System.out.println("Found sentinel value!  Breaking!");
        break;
    }
```

Try moving that test to the **end** of the loop.

Alternately, you could change the condition for your loop to:

```
while(scan.hasNext() && !carMake.equals(SECSENT))
```

Comment: It's still not reading the value in. I put it at the end and it still doesn't work.

Comment: How are you determining that it's not "reading" the value?  See the edit I made above with the "Found sentinel value!" printing.  It also might help if you were more precise with **exactly** what input you are feeding the program, and **exactly* what output you're getting, and how it differs from what you expect.

Comment: I'm determining this because I put in print statements to test if it was ever read in. I tried all the suggestions but it's still not working. Here's a sample input. Chevrolet 2003 12000.0
Lincoln 2007 32000.0
Lexus 2005 23678.0
Hyundai 2008 21000.0
Honda 2004 15500.0
EndDatabase
Lexus 2005 23678.0
Ford 2001 7595.0
Honda 2004 15500.0
EndSearchKeys    EndDatabase is the first sentinel and it exits its loop fine. and search keys is the second. When I put that as the input, it outputs all the print statements and then stalls after the last object is printed.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is to post the entire code and input file to pastebin or something and link here.  Too much missing information to determine what is happening exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the help I guess i'll just try to figure it out